# Nuget Packages Guidance

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, package

My question may seem silly.

I want to use various nuget packages in C# (VS 2017)>

I know how to find and install them but how can I find a guide on any of the packages about the methods, functions, parameters, etc?

For example, Web Helpers Package. I was not able to find a webpage on its abilities and how to use them.

Comment: There is a link to the project page on the nuget.org website. https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebHelpers/ - That project url should be available in Visual Studio 2017 in the UI I think.

Answer (score 0):

> Nuget Packages Guidance

Just like Matt said, if you want to find a guide on any of the packages about the methods, functions, parameters, you can go to the web page about this nuget package on the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/), then search the package on that web page:

[image]

Then you find some simple instructions about this package and a link [Project Site](https://github.com/wilby/WebHelpers).

You can open that link to get more info and source code about that package.

Hope this helps.